# Using log4net inside a IIS httphandler

Tags: c#, iis, log4net, httphandler, ihttphandler

I'm working on a project that uses a HTTPHandler (IIS) which powers an API. The HTTPHandler processes requests and gives back the response to whoever uses the API.

I'm trying to implement logging with Log4net. Normally, I would simply be able to call `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` whenever my application starts up. Putting this inside an assembly attribute inside `AssemblyInfo.cs` doesn't seem to work in this specific case. The log4net configuration is valid.

Is there any way to put initialization code inside the HTTPHandler? Or do I need to approach this differently?

Comment: can u share configuration?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://pastebin.com/3SqWkzqy

Comment: Assembly attribute loading can be tricky where there's no clearly defined entry point. Why can't you use `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` in the handler?